# NtQuerySystemInformation SystemHandleInformation filter only file handles

Tags: performance, cpu, cpu-usage

Every time that I call to NtQuerySystemInformation with SystemHandleInformation flag, I get 1%~ CPU and I think it's because the software get all the handles types of the system include FILES, EVENTS, TOKEN and more and there is a lot of handles.

1%~ CPU it's a lot for my software.

So my question is:
There is any why to get only the FILES handles type with filter in NtQuerySystemInformation or SystemHandleInformation and not getting all the handles types (without doing loop on all the handles and filter only the FILES handles)?

THANKS!

Comment: BTW: I also tried ZwQuerySystemInformation and it's also gave me 1%~ CPU

Comment: I also can't use Kernel Mode / Driver / Hooking.